# Parallogram law proof to show not a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question in a past exam which I have solutions to, however I am concerned that either I am misunderstanding the question or the teacher has made a small error. If someone could enlighten me I would be most grateful. Here it is

Consider the space $\mathbb R^2$ endowed with the norm $\|(x,y)\|=(|x|^3+|y|^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} $. Show that this space in not a Hilbert Space

So we have to find some vectors which do not satisfy the parallelogram law

Let $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$. Then we get

$\|u\|=\|v\|=1$

$\|u + v\|=\|u-v\|=2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ So that

$ \|u + v\|^2 + \|u - v\|^2= 2.2^{\frac{2}{3}}\ne4=2(\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2)$

hence the parallogram law doesn't hold and this is not a Hilbert Space

so, i am deeply confused, he says

$ \|u + v\|^2 + \|u - v\|^2= 2.2^{\frac{2}{3}}$,

is it not

$ \|u + v\|^2 + \|u - v\|^2= 2*2^{\frac{2}{3}}$ instead?

Surely
$\|u + v\|=\|u-v\|=2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ implies $\|u + v\|+\|u-v\|=2*2^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe he typed . rather than $\cdot$.

Comment: It's a typo/slip-up. In the paralelogram law, we have $\lVert u+v\rVert^2 + \lVert u-v\rVert^2$, not $\lVert u+v\rVert + \lVert u-v\rVert$.

Comment: sorry that was my typo!!! i meant the 2.2 really but 2 seconds will fix it

Comment: typo fixed.. now is this correct? I don't feel it is

Comment: Well, now we have $\lVert u+v\rVert^2 + \lVert u-v\rVert^2 = (2^{1/3})^2 + (2^{1/3})^2 = 2^{2/3} + 2^{2/3} = 2\cdot 2^{2/3}$.

Comment: ahh so it is a typo, he has put $2.2^{2/3}$.. makes sense now thanks a lot, having a stupid moment combined with a tiny typo